# Problem with stackoverflow front page?

Tags: bug, status-completed

After the 9th entry there are two columns of questions. (not always the 9th entry)

[See screenshot](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/3739/22965823.gif)

I am using IE7

**EDIT**

Looks like it is caused by a question from Nimbuz with no title

Comment: In which browser and OS? I don't see it in FF3.0.15 on Kubuntu

Comment: All good on **Opera**

Comment: @random do you see the adds on the righthand side?

Comment: Yes, even on Chrome (eww). But your screenshot shows at least three questions with no title.

Comment: @random it seems to be getting worse, now I see many questions without titles, and the font size increases for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, small change to encoding behavior with an accidental oversight..